Upgrade from .net 4.6.2 to .net core 8.0 WIN UI3 ASSEMBLY.LOADFROM(mydll.dll) in .net core 8.0 won't load
I have migrate my code from .net framework to.net core 8, and I have an issue with Assembly.LoadFrom(mydll.dll) which work fine with .net framwork, but is not working with .net core 8.0.  The assembly that I am trying to load has no dependency and is in the root directory of the application.
The following is the code I use in .net core.
    private void myButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        myButton.Content = "Clicked";
        var path = @"D:\Code\Trial\App1\App1\bin\x86\Debug\net8.0-windows10.0.18362.0\DT0WDX13";

        Assembly.LoadFrom(path);
    }

And the following I use in .net framwork
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        myButton.Content = "Clicked";
        var path = @"D:\Code\Trial\WpfApp1\WpfApp1\bin\Debug\DT0WDX13";

        Assembly.LoadFrom(path);
    }


I have figure it out, and it seems that there was something else in the code that was rejecting the load of the assembly, I wish the error was better explained.

You never posted any error message. .NET 8 is .NET Core 8, a completely different runtime and can't just load .NET Framework assemblies or use .NET Framework libraries and packages
